# Vertical placement of an image is taking my div out of flow of document

Tags: html, css

[image][image][image]I am trying to place an image vertically on the left side of screen (not vertical alignment in a div).

I have achieved this by using `transform: rotate(270deg)`, but as soon as I put this property `transform` in my CSS, it is taking the `div` out of flow. Then I used `position (top, left, bottom, right)` and used some crazy values like `-1800px`... to bring my `div` (with the image) to where I wanted it (left side, vertically)

The problem is, when I zoom out, my page is looking ugly. Can someone please suggest me a way to keep vertically place the image, but still prone to zoom in or zoom out

**HTML:**

```
<div class="leftSideLogo">
  <h1>Left side logo</h1>
  <img src="images/google_logo.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.leftSideLogotest
{
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: top top;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;       
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url("../images/google_logo.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}

.leftSideLogo
{
    //float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 375px;
    left: -500px;
    background-image: url("../images/google_logo.png");
    background-size: 70% 70%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    //transform: scale(1,1);
    //z-index: +1;
}

.leftSideLogo img
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: this is simple as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m607vwps/) I'm guessing you are confusing a lot, but your Code is short in HTML , at least for me to understand how can i really help you out.

Comment: I just tried it with this image - http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141030073231/respawnables/images/4/4a/Google-Play-logo-3300x746-transparent.png

It's going crazy again with your code :(


I have also tried background images in the div, still cannot achieve what I wanted simply. This is taking the div out of flow as well :(

Comment: The image is going into the center of the screen. I have to use position (top, left...) to bring it back to the corner. As soon as I use "transform", and zoom out or in, my website is looking ugly. If I have some div's with texts, they stick together no matter zoom in our out, but a div with rotated image is not

Comment: this image is 1600px width large when rotated it will have 1600px height! that's a big issue here! As i'm not seeing the full code i'm not fully able to help you at the moment.

Comment: That is all the code I have for this div (and image). The image will resize to it's parent containers height and width if I put a width: 100% (when not using transform property). As soon as I use transform, something crazy goes on.

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/evr4xnm2/) is what i've was able to in short time with not fully understanding the issue, let me know if that helps you, if so if you want me to turn into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were trying to get? See the demo follows (and comments inside).

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.left-logo {
    background: url("//dummyimage.com/200x50") 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 200px; /*max value of image size*/
    height: 200px; /*max value*/
    position: absolute; /*or fixed*/
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.main-area {
    background: gold;
    margin-left: 50px; /*min value*/
}
```

```html
<div class="left-logo"></div>
<div class="main-area">main area</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7epwvjho/

Comment: Yes. This is what I am trying to achieve, but only when I zoom out of the page, left-logo div and main-area div are not sticking together. The left-logo div will go all over the screen as I zoom in/out. Do you know if there is a way to make the html/css prone to zooming? I do not want to see the white spaces between the div's that are side by side :)

Comment: I am thinking this might be a bug with transform combined with images? :)

Comment: @PhaniAnne It looks fine here with zoom in/out, can you post a screenshot of the demo above with the problem that you see. Is your browser set to zoom text only? However I would rotate the image with an image editor, rather than do it with css.

Comment: **" I would rotate the image with an image editor, rather than do it with css"**. Why did I not think this of this the whole day? Instead I was just banging my head with css. This is me right now - [link]http://goo.gl/jtO5xc. Using a rotated image works very well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Do you know if **transform: rotate()** buggy? I used the same code you sent, but with a larger image (I have to work with a big images at my work!). Have uploaded a detailed image again! **You can see the screenshot with your code here - http://s9.postimg.org/f6h1uff0v/sdcr.jpg**

Comment: @PhaniAnne I wouldn't say if it's buggy or not, as I'm really not sure. it seems fine with large image in the updated demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7epwvjho/1/ however the unwanted horizontal scroll bar shows up, but can be fixed with overflow-x:hidden.